# Electron app that gets data located on a Raspberry PI

Tags: javascript, python, raspberry-pi, electron

i'm in the process of creating my first app with the use of Electron. The app is basically finished and I only have one thing left to do. I've got a Raspberry PI that is running a Python script and writes data to a file. Is it possible for me to get the data located in that file on the PI and read it to my Electron app on another PC on the same network and display it?

This is the first time i'm working on something requiring this kind of functionality so i'm not really sure how to implement such a feature. The Electron app should be able to be downloaded from multiple PCs on the same network and they all need to be able to access and read the data on the PI.

Thanks in advance, I'll happily clarify if what i'm asking is difficult to understand.

Comment: What you need is an API on your raspberry. From that you'll be able to `ask` your raspberry to give you the data you need (here, the file). If you publish your API on internet then everybody with your application will be able to retrieve the data and display everything correctly.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks

Comment: What did you do ?